# How to copy all directories without numbers in directory name

Tags: linux

How do I copy all sub-directories whose names do not contain numbers to a new destination?

Say I have under `DIRECTORY_A` three sub-directories, `./DDD`, `./III` and `./DDD1`. How can I use something like:

```
cp -r DIRECTORY/*[!0-9]* NEW_DIRECTORY/
```

and only have `./DDD` and `./III` copied to `NEW_DIRECTORY`?

Answer (score 0):

```
cd DIRECTORY_A
for directory_in_a in *
do
    cp -Trfv "$directory_in_a" "../DIRECTORY_B/$(printf %s "$directory_in_a" | sed 's/[0-9]*$//')"
done
```

`cp` options explanation:

- `-T` — Move *into* existing directory instead creating subdirectory in it
- `-r` — Copy recursively
- `-v` — Print information about copied files/directories
- `-f` — Force overwriting existing files and use existing directories

The `$(printf %s "$directory_in_a" | sed 's/[0-9]*$//')` construct inserts output of `printf %s "$directory_in_a" | sed 's/[0-9]*$//'` to the string.

- `printf %s "$directory_in_a"` outputs value of the variable
- `sed 's/[0-9]*$//'` removes all digits at end of lines of the stdin